# Nesting IF and ISBLANK

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

Please help. I'm trying to get the cell to return blank but I'm having trouble.

```
=IF(AND($I2>1,AG2>=0.5),1,IF(AND($I2<1,AG2<0.5),1,IF(AG2=""),"",0))
```

There's and error message when I include the last argument IF(AG2=""),"",0.

This alternative hasn't worked either `=IF(ISBLANK(AG2),"",IF(AND($I2>1,AG2>=0.5),1,IF(AND($I2<1,AG2<0.5),1,0)))`

I've also tried with using IFERROR to return blank rather than DIV/O which ruins my pivot table. Thanks so much

Comment: Why the tag `R`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(AND($I2>1,AG2>=0.5),1,IF(AND($I2<1,AG2<0.5),1,IF(AG2="","",0)))
```

Your error was parenthetical.

Comment: Correct. I deleted my duplicate answer posted shortly after this one